# Какие инструменты есть для реализации грамматик?

Tags: python, python-3.x, запрос, грамматика, influxdb

Есть задача подмены токенов в [InfluxQL](https://github.com/influxdata/influxql/blob/master/README.md) запросах. Синтаксис этих запросов определён [расширенной формой Бэкуса — Наура](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). Какие в [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) есть библиотеки для реализации этой грамматики, чтобы потом осуществить разбор InfluQL запроса, получить дерево токенов и подменить необходимые мне токены? В идеале бы ещё хотелось увидеть пример разбора какого-нибудь простейшего запроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как обычно, удалось что-то нагуглить уже после того, как задал вопрос. Нашёл модуль [parsimonious](https://pypi.org/project/parsimonious/) (более обширная документация есть на [странице github проекта](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious)). Он, правда, малость кастрированный (только жадные квантификаторы), но работать уже можно.
Пример урезанной грамматики для создания пользователя и удаления БД:

```
query               = statement ('; ' statement)*
statement           = create_user_stmt / drop_database_stmt
create_user_stmt    = 'CREATE USER ' user_name ' WITH PASSWORD ' password ' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES'?
drop_database_stmt  = 'DROP DATABASE ' db_name
user_name           = identifier ''
password            = string_lit ''
db_name             = identifier ''
identifier          = unquoted_identifier / quoted_identifier
string_lit          = "'" (letter / digit)* "'"
unquoted_identifier = letter (letter / digit)*
quoted_identifier   = '"' letter+ '"'
letter              = ascii_letter / '_'
digit               = ~'[0-9]'
ascii_letter        = ~'[a-z]'i
```

---

Пример разбора запроса и подмены токенов `user_name`, `password` и `db_name`:

```py
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor, Node
from base64 import b64encode


class InfluxQLVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    def visit_user_name(self, node: Node, visited_children):
        return b64encode(node.text.encode()).decode()  # Вместо имени пользователя возвращаем base64 от него
    
    visit_password = visit_user_name  # То же самое для password
    
    visit_db_name = visit_user_name  # То же самое для db_name
    
    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return ''.join(visited_children) or node.text  # Для неопределенных токенов возвращаем просто их текст


with open('influxql.grammar', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:  # Считывание грамматики из файла
    influxql_grammar = Grammar(fp.read())  # Чтобы не заморачиваться с экранированием символов

# Запрос для разбора
query = """CREATE USER "jdoe" WITH PASSWORD '1337password' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES; DROP DATABASE my_secret_db"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = influxql_grammar.parse(query)  # Получение дерева разбора запроса
    
    visitor = InfluxQLVisitor()
    res = visitor.visit(tree)  # Обход дерева с заменой необходимых токенов
    print(res)
```

---

Столкнулся с тем, что парсер по умолчанию не различает контекста. Т.е., если убрать из определения токенов `user_name`, `db_name` и `password` пустую строку в конце, то после разбора эти токены будут являться токенами типа `identifier` и `string_lit`. Фикс такого кейса предложен на [github](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious/issues/131#issuecomment-353739447).